# Open a note or display dialog with application

Tags: macos, applescript, final-cut-pro

I work with a colleague editing videos and I wish to trigger a dialog or a note document whenever he opens Final Cut, so I can leave messages for him to do the job. The machine has to stay always on, so I can't use any startup  method.

It's the same workstation same user account, we share the room in different shifts.

El Capitan 10.11.6 - FinalCut Pro 7 -- He enters after 18pm

**Any advice on how to display a message when opening an application?**

Comment: where is he, how are you connected , what HW,SW are you using. Help us to help you. If same machine, does he has his own user account ?

Comment: It's the same workstation, we share the room in different shifts.

Comment: please answer all my questions, specialty the one if he has his own user account. How would system know it was him opening the Final Cut and not you. We could use the time stamp if that does not changes. Always same shit.

Comment: Yes, same account. Its the same computer, I just leave early and he assumes later.

Comment: El Capitan 10.11.6 - FinalCut Pro 7 -- He enters after 18pm

Comment: Its OK if the note is displayed to me.

Comment: Might I suggest leaving a note open on the desktop just before you leave so it's there for when he arrives ?  Simplest solutions are often the most effective.

Comment: CJK I agree, its a good idea. However sometimes there are power failures and other people using the machine, so it would be nice to have a reliable method...

Comment: thank you for the input. The problem is to have a programmable input message (imputed by you that changes) otherwise it is always the same message.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Maybe the script could retrieve the message from a NOTES.txt file. Or I can edit a service/app using the Script Editor. My real issue is triggering the message. Im thinking about just leaving a "display dialog" open.

Comment: If you want to be fancé, then you can setup a web server with Apache and PHP (both preinstalled). Use https://github.com/henck/rtf-html-php to parse RTF document as HTML. Host the notes file on there. Your colleague can open the website to view the message.

Comment: If you want to be ULTRA fancé (I know), you can setup a chat so you can send messages back and forth. But then why not just use an IM program? Or Email.

Comment: @JBis Thanks for your ideas. I thought there was something easy, like a script to keep track of open applications or something. I just want something cool to mess with him or alert for something. Of course we already use Slack and emails.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro I could throw a script together but its not gonna be could. I would highly suggest you stick with Slack and emails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a Apple script (in your Utility folder Script Editor) that will open Notes if the Final Cut is opened.

I don't have Final Cut so I used Skype to test. Just copy and paste following, then save.

```
repeat until application "Final Cut Pro" is running
    delay 1
end repeat

delay 5
if application "Final Cut Pro" is running then activate application "Notes"
```

The Delay 5 (seconds) is to have Notes as Top window after Final Cut starts. You can increase that number.
This script will run continuously until Final Cut is started, but we could go fancy and have it start at 18:00.

Prerequisite is you Quit the Final cut before you leave.

As always you can be very elaborate leaving a message and instructions in Note.

Also set Notes in Preference to sort by date created so to have the latest note on the top.

Comment: "AppleScript" isn't in the "Utility" folder.  However, _Script Editor_ is in the "Utilities" folder of the "Applications" folder.  Testing the app with _Skype_ is reasonable, but why not then replace it with _Final Cut_ yourself before submitting the answer, instead of suggesting the reader does it ?  It makes no sense to leave it like that.  The `appName` variable is superfluous: makes more sense to just say `if application "Final Cut" is running then`, and subsequently `activate application "Notes"`. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_  In fact, that ***is*** your entire script in one line: `if application "Final Cut" is running then activate application "Notes"`.  The rest of it is unneeded junk.  That said, I don't believe this answer solves the OP's solution at all as it currently stands.  If the OP runs your script as it is, it'll either launch _Notes_, or it won't, then it terminates.  That's not especially useful.

Comment: `open location` is also not a _Notes_ command.  There's a command called `open notes location` but it requires a URL to a pre-existing note. As a final point, I just did a Google search and it turns out _Final Cut (Pro)_ ***isn't*** scriptable (unless that information is out-of-date).  This means you can't use the `running` property to check if it's running.  Therefore, the script will fail to execute. I feel this answer needs to be radically improved with further details and corrections, or deleted as being insufficient and an example of incorrect AppleScripting.

Comment: You're welcome and well done for taking the critique on the chin.  I noticed you revised your script.  On a minor note, you don't need `if application "Skype" is running then...`, as if the script gets that far, it means the `repeat` loop has been broken, so you ***know*** the application ***is*** running.  You simply need `activate application "Notes"`.  On a slightly less minor note, it's still not a practical script to use as it requires _Script Editor_ to remain open and the script to be left running on a loop. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_  I'm glad you ignored my comment about _Final Cut Pro_ not being scriptable, as I was incorrect in assuming that was a necessary mandate for the `running` property to be readable.  It turns out it is a core property for all `application` objects in AppleScript, regardless of scriptability.  I still feel you ought to replace `"Skype"` with `"Final Cut Pro"` yourself.  Leaving it in makes no sense and is confusing at a simple glance (most people head straight for the code first, and not the prose).

Comment: But, overall, this is a much better version than the first offering, so kudos. (I didn't downvote you in case you're wondering.)

Comment: @CJK once you have over 30k you do not pay much attention to up or down, and I am not interested in installing a new app each time and spend $299 .

Comment: Why would you need to install _Final Cut Pro_ ?  At no point was that a suggestion, and I would never advise doing something like that.

Comment: @CJK I had to test it, so used Skype.

Comment: I understand that.  I don't own _Final Cut Pro_ either.  But you can test your script with _Skype_, then just substitute the word "Skype" with "Final Cut Pro" immediately before pasting the script into your anwer, or just before submitting your answer.  Simples.  It's exactly what you've advised the reader to do - so why not just do it yourself for them and avoid the hoohah ?

Comment: Worked like a charm! So simple. Thank you very much @Buscar웃

Comment: @MateusRibeiro you are welcome :)

Comment: @MateusRibeiro If this is the answer you went for, then why not just leave the _Notes_ app open after you end your shift?  There is no benefit to using a script like this, and, indeed, it leaves the _Script Editor_ open and exposed on the machine that you said other people are using, meaning they can edit the script to do whatever they want instead.  This is a terrible solution to a problem that doesn’t need a script to solve.

Comment: @CJK you are clearly scripting guru. However, understanding the human psyche can be tricky! There is a big difference in leaving Notes open, somewhere buried under other windows, and having it pop up right in yo the face of the targeted user.

Comment: I’m no guru.  But, without meaning to be rude, @wch1zpink’s answer does the same thing and in a far superior manner.  He’s also explained to the OP how to implement his script correctly.  Yours simply wastes system resources by running on a loop, and exposes _Script Editor_ to the general public.  But, it is the OP’s decision, and they are free to do as they please.

Comment: @CJK And he does not need to use the "Final Cut" ? That is strange ! The difference is in one case you can leave a text message (limited) or leave elaborate instructions with examples. I do not understand the exposure with Script Editor. That system is open to all users as OP stated.

Comment: OK.  Yes, I should have prodded him about that too, but there were other issues being discussed that were more important.  He’s a better scripter so I tend to give him a hard time to make his code better, but with yours, I was just focusing on the small stuff because the rest was broken anyway.  But both of you took criticism well, so you both deserve a pat on the back for trying to help the OP do what he wants.

Comment: @CJK I just think that using notes is easier than editing the app every time. Plus as I stated somewhere there are sometimes power failures and people using other apps so the window would be indeed buried. The loop is very light, but I will implement a quit application after popping, so no harm done. Also, for the glory of Satan. :D But yeah the other answer is helpful too. I wish to reward the other guy for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have “Final Cut.app” so I tested this code with the TextEdit.app.  If you save this code in Script Editor as a stay open application, on first run, this app will display a dialog box for you to input the message that you want the person opening “Final Cut” to read. If the Final Cut closes or unexpectedly quits…. On reopen of Final Cut, the original dialog you previously set, will be displayed again.  When you quit the stay open app and then relaunch it again…. That dialog box will once again appear asking you to enter the message that you want the person opening “Final Cut” to read.

```
property theApp : "TextEdit" -- Change this
property theMessage : missing value
property appIsRunning : missing value

activate
set theMessage to text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "THE MESSAGE" default answer ¬
    "Message You Want To Display" buttons ¬
    "OK" default button ¬
    "OK" with title ¬
    "Message You Want To Display" with icon 2)

on idle
    repeat
        repeat until appIsRunning is true
            delay 5 -- avoids dialog and theApp (if relaunching) opening at same time
            set appIsRunning to application theApp is running
            if appIsRunning is true then
                activate
                -- Running A Display Dialog Within An Application Tell Block... 
                -- Inherits The Apps Icon To Be Used In The Dialog Window
                tell application theApp to display dialog theMessage buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" with icon 1
            end if
        end repeat
        -- next line necessary to re-trigger the "repeat until" loop again
        set appIsRunning to application theApp is running
        return 5 -- in seconds
    end repeat
end idle
```

Comment: May I prod you to double-check to see whether you need the outside `repeat` loop in your `on idle` handler ?  Given that the handler is, itself, executed every 5 seconds (from your `return 5`), I suspect it's superfluous.  My second query is whether you would be getting rid of `if appIsRunning is true then` moving the contents of that block to just outside the inner `repeat` loop, which only really serves as a monitor on a delay cycle.  Once the loop is broken, you _know_ that `appIsRunning` is true, so the dialog can be displayed; then there's also no need to `set appIsRunning` a second time.

Comment: In fact, just bin the `appIsRunning` property altogether.  You only effectively utilise it once, so it's not serving any real value.  You can simply do: `repeat until application theApp is running`...`delay 5`...`end repeat`.  Then `activate` and `display dialog`, then `return 5`.

Comment: Trimmed off as much of the fat as I could and added a few commented descriptions.  Thank you all... for the pointers

Comment: @CJK  I tried your suggestion of `repeat until application theApp is running` ... Does not work correctly. Running the stay open application with the adjusted code that you suggested... Always forces the target application to open If it is closed

Comment: I just tested your script with my two suggestions above implemented, as a _Stay Open_ application, tested with _TextEdit_ as the target application.  The applet/script runs exactly as expected, and _doesn't_ force the target application to launch (**_System info:_** _AppleScript version_: "2.7", _system version_: "10.13.6").  As I suspected, the outside `repeat` loop is demonstrably unnecessary in my test.  Mind you, this is more "FYI". Your script _does_ work, so I suppose all I'm doing is nitpicking.